# A problem for table function after filtering rows

Tags: r

In the case I need to create a cross tabulation of restaurant types against cluster. And I choose three types of restaurant, which are Indian, Korean, and Pizza. 
However, there are many other types of restaurant. Therefore I use filter() to select my aim.

```
rest_3cui <- rest1 %>% filter(Cuisine %in% c('Indian', 'Korean', 'Pizza'))

table(rest_3cui[, c('Cuisine', 'cluster')])
```

However, it show like that:

```
                  cluster
Cuisine             1 2 3
  Asian             0 0 0
  Bakery            0 0 0
  Burger            0 0 0
  Cafe Food         0 0 0
  Charcoal Chicken  0 0 0
  Chinese           0 0 0
  Coffee and Tea    0 0 0
  Desserts          0 0 0
  Dumplings         0 0 0
  European          0 0 0
  Fast Food         0 0 0
  Fish and Chips    0 0 0
  French            0 0 0
  Greek             0 0 0
  Hot Pot           0 0 0
  Indian            4 0 1
  Italian           0 0 0
  Japanese          0 0 0
  Korean            2 2 2
  Korean BBQ        0 0 0
  Lebanese          0 0 0
  Malaysian         0 0 0
  Mediterranean     0 0 0
  Mexican           0 0 0
  Modern Australian 0 0 0
  Pizza             1 0 5
  Portuguese        0 0 0
  Pub Food          0 0 0
  Ramen             0 0 0
  Russian           0 0 0
  Sandwich          0 0 0
  Sushi             0 0 0
  Thai              0 0 0
  Tibetan           0 0 0
  Vietnamese        0 0 0
```

which contain too many other useless messages instead of only three targets.
My intended table should be:

```
                 cluster
Cuisine           1 2 3
Indian            4 0 1
Korean            2 2 2
Pizza             1 0 5
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

That is mostly because `Cuisine` is of type `factor`. Consider this example using `mtcars` data

```
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
table(df[, c("cyl", "am")])

#   am
#cyl  0  1
#  4  3  8
#  6  4  3
#  8 12  2
```

Now we remove one level

```
df2 <- subset(df, cyl != 4)
table(df2[, c("cyl", "am")])
#   am
#cyl  0  1
#  4  0  0
#  6  4  3
#  8 12  2
```

We still have a row where `cyl = 4`. We need to drop that level. One way is to convert it to character

```
df2$cyl <- as.character(df2$cyl)
table(df2[, c("cyl", "am")])
#   am
#cyl  0  1
#  6  4  3
#  8 12  2
```

Or we want to keep it as `factor`, use `factor` again so unused levels are dropped

```
df2$cyl <- factor(df2$cyl)
```

Or `droplevels`

```
df2$cyl <- droplevels(df2$cyl)
```

---

In your case, you can add `droplevels` after the `filter` and it should work fine.

```
library(dplyr)

rest_3cui <- rest1 %>% 
               filter(Cuisine %in% c('Indian', 'Korean', 'Pizza')) %>% 
               droplevels()
```